# How to show the search icon (magnifying glass) to the right of text in ExtJS string filters?

Tags: css, extjs, filter

I haven't found a way to do it in the documentation and I wanted to ask here before I start hacking my way though this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using:
labelStyle: 'position: absolute; right: 0;'

I also messed with width, and fieldStyle to make it look exactly like I wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add a [trigger](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.field.Text.html#cfg-triggers) to your textfield.

Ex:

```
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            fieldLabel: 'My Text Field',
                            triggers: {
                                searchTrigger: {
                                    handler: function(field, trigger, e) {
                                        console.log('your search code');
                                    },
                                    cls: 'fa-search'
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Hello michwalk I have try this but not showing Any icon of search.

Comment: Hey Pravin! You need to have font awesome set up for that to work http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'text',
    triggers:
    {
         search:{
               cls: 'x-form-search-trigger',
               handler: function () {
               }

        }
    }
}
```

you get result like this.

[image: you get result like this.]

Answer (score 1):

Its a tricky thing to do actually. so here is my solution for it
I changed the Style of the cross icon and the magnifying glass icon by adding position relative and some left value according to where you want it, and increasing the text field width.

```css
#searchField .x-form-text-default
{
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    
}
#searchField .x-form-clear-trigger, .x-form-clear-trigger-default
{
    position: relative;
    left: 22px;
}
#searchField .x-form-search-trigger
{
    position: relative;
    left: 26px;
}
```